# How to skip the 1st key in an array loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
if ($_POST['submit'] == "Next") {
    foreach($_POST['info'] as $key => $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

How do I get the foreach function to start from the 2nd key in the array?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

For reasonably small arrays, use [array_slice](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to create a second one:

```
foreach(array_slice($_POST['info'],1) as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Excellent use of array_slice superb

Comment: How about ridiculously large arrays?

Answer (score 46):

```
foreach(array_slice($_POST['info'], 1) as $key=>$value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Alternatively if you don't want to copy the array you could just do:

```
$isFirst = true;
foreach($_POST['info'] as $key=>$value) {
    if ($isFirst) {
        $isFirst = false;
        continue;
    }   
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: I like the isFirst solution better.
Its in your face logic, the array slice version could easily be missed when scanning unfamiliar code.

Comment: The isFirst solution is also scales better with array size.

Answer (score 32):

Couldn't you just unset the array...

So if I had an array where I didn't want the first instance, 
I could just:

```
unset($array[0]);
```

and that would remove the instance from the array.

Comment: In this scenario yes, but what if you wanted to do some comparison between the 2nd value in the array with the 1st value?

Answer (score 6):

If you were working with a normal array, I'd say to use something like

`foreach (array_slice($ome_array, 1) as $k => $v {...`

but, since you're looking at a user request, you don't have any real guarantees on the order in which the arguments might be returned - some browser/proxy might change its behavior or you might simply decide to modify your form in the future.  Either way, it's in your best interest to ignore the ordering of the array and treat POST values as an unordered hash map, leaving you with two options :

- copy the array and `unset` the key you want to ignore
- loop through the whole array and `continue` when seeing the key you wish to ignore

Comment: From http://www.php.net/types.array : "An array in PHP is actually an ordered map".  They act sorta strangely.

Answer (score 5):

in loop:

```
if ($key == 0) //or whatever
   continue;
```

Comment: I tend to advise against testing for 'special cases' in a loop, if they are known upfront (i.e. the first entry) -> -1

Comment: I don't the exact reason for @xtofl but for me, the problem is you have to test every time the loop runs if you are in the special case

Answer (score 4):

Alternative way is to use array pointers:

```
reset($_POST['info']); //set pointer to zero
while ($value=next($_POST['info'])  //ponter+1, return value
{
  echo key($_POST['info']).":".$value."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to throw the first element away, you can use `array_shift()`. However, this is slow on a huge array. A faster operation would be

```
reset($a);
unset(key($a));
```

Comment: Really?  How huge would `array_shift()` become slow for?  And why would `unset` be faster?

Comment: Ya know, I can't remember why I answered this. Haven't needed this trick in a long time, but I probably got a speedup onceuponatime by doing it the other way! I would imagine an array of some tens of Mb in size might have a difference.

Comment: ACTUALLY!!  `array_shift()` is POISON!! It actually __re-numbers__ all numerical array indices -- even if they are initially sparse (e.g. an array defined `array(1=>'a', 3=>'b', 99=>'c')` would become equivalent to `array('0'=>'b', '1'=c)` after an `array_shift()` operation.  Don't `array_shift()` unless this is what you want!!

Comment: And so yes, hence why this is faster.  The re-indexing operation takes a lot of time.

Comment: Well done for doing the research yourself. Just a note that sometimes the keys don't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Working Code From My Website For Skipping The First Result and Then Continue.

```
<?php 

$counter = 0;

foreach ($categoriest as $category) { if ($counter++ == 0) continue; ?>
```

It is working on opencart also in tpl file do like this in case you need.

Answer (score 1):

On a array filled with 1000 elements the difference is quite minimal.

**Test:**

```
<?php
function slice($a)
{
    foreach(array_slice($a, 1) as $key)
    {

    }

    return true;
}

function skip($a)
{
    $first = false;

    foreach($a as $key)
    {
        if($first)
        {
            $first = false;
            continue;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

$array = array_fill(0, 1000, 'test');

$t1 = time() + microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    slice($array);
}

var_dump((time() + microtime(true)) - $t1);

echo '<hr />';

$t2 = time() + microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    skip($array);
}

var_dump((time() + microtime(true)) - $t2);
?>
```

**Output:**

float(0.23605012893677)

float(0.24102783203125)

Comment: I think it is memory usage that is the more important difference here - maybe measure with memory_get_usage()

Comment: 11 years later, but in your skip function, should't `first` start with being true?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST['info'] as $key=>$value) {
    if ($key == 0) { //or what ever the first key you're using is
        continue;
    }  else { 
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you structure your form differently

```
  <input type='text' name='quiz[first]' value=""/>
  <input type='text' name='quiz[second]' value=""/>
```

...then in your PHP

```
if( isset($_POST['quiz']) AND 
    is_array($_POST['quiz'])) {

    //...and we'll skip $_POST['quiz']['first'] 
    foreach($_POST['quiz'] as $key => $val){
      if($key == "first") continue;
      print $val; 
    }
}
```

...you can now just loop over that particular structure and access rest normally

Comment: How about you use integers instead of strings?  (Even though technically it's sent over as a string, it's easier to debug (and generate!) with integers.)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?  Read off the first key and value using `key()` and `current()`, then <del>`array_shift()` to dequeue the front element from the array</del> (EDIT:  Don't use `array_shift()`, it renumbers any numerical indices in the array, which you don't always want!).

```
    <?php

    $arr = array(

      'one' => "ONE!!",
      'two' => "TWO!!",
      'three' => "TREE",
      4 => "Fourth element",
      99 => "We skipped a few here.."

    ) ;

    $firstKey = key( $arr ) ;
    $firstVal = current( $arr ) ;

    echo( "OK, first values are $firstKey, $firstVal" ) ;
    ####array_shift( $arr ) ; #'dequeue' front element # BAD! renumbers!
    unset( $arr[ $firstKey ] ) ;  # BETTER!

    echo( "Now for the rest of them" ) ;
    foreach( $arr as $key=>$val )
    {
      echo( "$key => $val" ) ;
    }

    ?>
```