# skipping first entry of a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I want to skip the first entry of a foreach loop, I know a way to do it, but it uses a lot of lines of code, I was wondering if there was an easier way:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($url AS $u) {
    if($i!=0) $cats[check_url($u)] = $u;
    $i++;
}
```

Is there a better more official way?

Comment: `foreach($url as $k=>$u){ if($k==0)continue; ... }` Or just remove the first value in the array. Or use for for loop instead and start that at 1.

Comment: How do I remove the first value in an array?

Comment: @JackQueen  use unset(array[0]); to do that

Comment: @JackQueen to remove the first value of an array correctly, use `array_shift()`. If you need to use it, save it to a variable, if not, simply use the function. To remove the last element, use `array_pop()`. Use array functions!

Comment: @Zapp shouldn't work, his `$i++` is inside the loop so, using `continue` will end up with skipping all items.

Comment: Trying to find reference, I found a Possible duplicate: [How to skip the 1st key in an array loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371554/how-to-skip-the-1st-key-in-an-array-loop)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach would be to use PHP's built in array_shift() function to pop the first item off the array before looping through.

If you aren't sure how your $url array is indexed, simply removing index [0] with `unset($url[0])` may or may not solve the problem. For example, if $url is indexed by association, it may look more like this:

```
$url['first'] = "a value";
$url['second'] = "some other value";
$url['third'] = "a different value";
```

To be certain you are excluding the first "indexed" element, regardless of the key associated with it, you can use array_shift() like so:

```
array_shift($url);
```

This pops off the first element and reset()s the array pointer.

After this you can carry out your foreach loop like normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have numeric keys for `$url` you can simply do like this :

```
foreach($url AS $k => $u) {
    if($k) $cats[check_url($u)] = $u;
}
```

But if your array has non numeric keys, I think what you have is the best way to do!