# How to skip first item in a foreach loop in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I am trying to fill my webpage with content based on content stored in a database. However, I would like to skip the first item; I want to start looping from the second item.

How can I achieve this?

```
@foreach($aboutcontent as $about)
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     <img id="" class="img-responsive" src="images/{{ $about->aboutimg }}" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3>{{ $about->aboutname }}</h3>
            <p>{{ $about->aboutinfo }}</p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `@foreach(array_slice($aboutcontent, 1) as $about)` perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip the 1st key in an array loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371554/how-to-skip-the-1st-key-in-an-array-loop)

Comment: They are all good answers thank you all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try This :

```
@foreach($aboutcontent as $key => $about)
@if($key > 0){ 
   <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
       <div class="thumbnail">
         <img id="" class="img-responsive" src="images/{{ $about->aboutimg }}" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>{{ $about->aboutname }}</h3>
                <p>{{ $about->aboutinfo }}</p>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
@endif;
@endforeach
```

Comment: The keys might not be numeric, or not zero-indexed, and then the condition might evaluate to `true` even though it's the first element of the array.

Answer (score 29):

As of Laravel 5.4, whenever you use `foreach` or `for` within blade files you will now have access to a [$loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable). The $loop variable provides many useful properties and methods, one of them being useful here, for skipping the first iteration. See the example below, which is a much cleaner way of achieving the same result as the other older answers here:

```
@foreach ($rows as $row)
    @if ($loop->first) @continue @endif
    {{ $row->name }}<br/>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the `$aboutcontents` is numeric array just use the good old fashioned `for` loop instead of your new fangled `foreach`

```
// Notice you start at 1 and your first
// elem is 0 so... ta da... skipped
@for ($i = 1; $i < count($aboutcontents); $i++){
    $about = $aboutcontents[$i]; //This is the object

    //now use $about as you would
}
```

*Note: I have not used Larvel or blades but based on the docs this should be doable*

Comment: The keys might not be numeric, or not zero-indexed, and then accessing the elements from the array might fail.

Answer (score 3):

There is two way to do this:
1- if your $key is numeric you can use:

```
@foreach($aboutcontent as $key => $about)
 @if($key == 0)
  @continue
 @endif
 code
@endforeach
```

2- if a $key is not numeric 
use @loop->first as a condition

Answer (score 2):

You need some kind of a counter if you want to do that in blade:

```
<?php $count = 0;?>
@foreach
    @if($count>1)
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
           <div class="thumbnail">
             <img id="" class="img-responsive" src="images/{{ $about->aboutimg }}" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>{{ $about->aboutname }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ $about->aboutinfo }}</p>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    @endif
    $count++
@endforeach
```

EDIT:

I like the answer provided by Mark Baker in the comment better

```
@foreach(array_slice($aboutcontent, 1) as $about)
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     <img id="" class="img-responsive" src="images/{{ $about->aboutimg }}" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3>{{ $about->aboutname }}</h3>
            <p>{{ $about->aboutinfo }}</p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can just remove the first element from the array before iterating:

```
@php
    array_shift($aboutcontent);
@endphp
@foreach($aboutcontent as $about)
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img id="" class="img-responsive" src="images/{{ $about->aboutimg }}" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3>{{ $about->aboutname }}</h3>
            <p>{{ $about->aboutinfo }}</p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

The advantage is that you do not need any conditions to verify you are not the in the first iteration. The disadvantage is that you might need the first element within the same view, but that we don't know from your example.

**Note** It might make more sense to remove the first element from the array *before* you pass on the data to the view.

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#php

Comment: This will work in some cases, but usually you are iterating trough laravel collection not array...

Answer (score 1):

As of Laravel 5.3 you can use `@continue($loop->first)`

```php
@foreach($aboutcontent as $about)
@continue($loop->first)

...

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@foreach($aboutcontent->slice(1) as $about)
       <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
       <div class="thumbnail">
         <img id="" class="img-responsive" src="images/{{ $about->aboutimg }}" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>{{ $about->aboutname }}</h3>
                <p>{{ $about->aboutinfo }}</p>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: can you elaborate on why should the op try this?