# How can I skip the first post in WordPress loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to skip or don't show first post.
how can I do skip firs post?

```
              <?php query_posts('cat=' . $tabish['opt-box1'] . '&showposts' . $tabish['opt-box1-count']); ?> 
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="section-left-title">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>
                                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                                </a>
                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted"><?php the_time('d M Y'); ?> </small></p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip the 1st key in an array loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371554/how-to-skip-the-1st-key-in-an-array-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=' . $tabish['opt-box1'] . '&showposts' . $tabish['opt-box1-count'] ); 
    $i = 0; 
    while( have_posts() ) { the_post(); 
        if( $i > 0 ){ ?>
            <div class="section-left-title">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted"><?php the_time('d M Y'); ?> </small></p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php 
        } 
        $i++; 
    } 
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: I have this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE)`

Comment: I used the edited code, unfortunately it does not display any posts

Comment: Do you have posts? where are you putting this code?

Comment: I putted this code, unfortunately it does not display any posts

Comment: does it displaying before?