# PHP - Create ArrayIterator with offset

Tags: php, arrays, iterator, offset

Maybe silly question, but I have an array and I would like to create an ArrayIterator but with an offset.

Example, I've the following array :

```
$fruits = [
  1 => 'banana',
  2 => 'apple',
  3 => 'orange',
  ...
  20 => 'raspberry'
]
```

My offset is 3.

I want to create an ArrayIterator with the $fruits array and the $offset.
How can I do that ? I don't understand the ArrayIterator doc'.
There is the OffsetSet() method but I don't understand how it works

Comment: You mean to skip the first x elements in an array, yes? Or what do you mean by offset?

Comment: Yes that's it, ignore the first x elements

Comment: [How to skip the 1st key in an array loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371554/how-to-skip-the-1st-key-in-an-array-loop) (you should be able to change the first given answer to skip the first x elements)

Comment: _“Yes that's it, ignore the first x elements”_ - then you appear to have misunderstood what `offsetSet` does to begin with. See here for an explanation of what it actually does: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-arrayiterator-offsetset-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either skip while you're looping or use `array_splice` to create a new array from your offset onwards.

```
$obj = new ArrayObject( array_slice($fruits, 3) );
$it = $obj->getIterator();
```